# I want to use extensions list at the time of "save as" option in File Dialog for file write in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, qfiledialog

I want to use extensions list example : [".txt",".html",".css"] for save as option in file dialog popup window. when I use this method

```
file_opt = options = {}
options['defaultextension'] = '.txt'
```

,I can able to write any file with .txt as default extension without choose in save as option but I want to choose extensions for save as in file dialog popup window from using my extensions list.
I'm using Python 3.5 based Anaconda IDE

Comment: To get better help, you should post the code that shows the file dialog. Apart from the `tkinter` tag in your question, there's no way to even know what tools you're using

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm) you can see that you can pass in the `filetypes` keyword which specifies a list of tuples that have the name, and file extension respectively for the different types of filetypes you want to be able to save as.. So you can do something along the lines of:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

def save_file():

    filename = fd.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.txt', 
         filetypes= [('Text','.txt'), ('HTML', '.html'), ('CSS', '.css')])
    if filename:
        print("User saved the filename with extension:", filename.split(".")[-1])

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Save File', command=save_file)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Or if you really want to use a dictionary for this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

SAVE_OPTS = {'defaultextension':'.txt', 
             'filetypes': [('Text','.txt'), ('HTML', '.html'), ('CSS', '.css')]}

def save_file():

    filename = fd.asksaveasfilename(**SAVE_OPTS)
    if filename:
        print("User saved the filename with extension:", filename.split(".")[-1])

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Save File', command=save_file)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It Works, Thanks for Answer! But I can't tick this answer as useful because I have no reputation and It requires 15. But again Thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();
sd.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt|PNG File (*.txt)|*.png"|...;

if(sd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    richTextBox1.SaveFile(sd.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
}
```

Comment: Hello Syed! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: here the extensions may added after the object is created here as "sd" where it adds multiple extensions after the "|" OR sign. Thanks